# On iPhone, Gmail "new email" notifications keep appearing in lock screen?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, gmail, notifications, screen-lock

On my iPhone, for the Gmail app, I sometimes get "new email" notifications on my lock screen that were from hours ago even when I cleared them (I unlocked the device after they appeared).

Even when the lock screen is clear of notifications, then one of these from Gmail appears, it will have the timestamp from a few hours ago rather than from "now".

Comment: How many email accounts do you have set up on your iPhone? Are you using the Gmail app or Mail? When you added your account, did you add a "Gmail" account or a Microsoft Exchange account? What's your notification schedule? What version of iOS are you running? Is it jailbroken? Why do you have ipod-touch tagged? Are you also experiencing this issue on an iPhone? Have you noticed a pattern to when you get the new email notifications (ie, right after connecting or disconnecting from wifi)?

Comment: I'm using the Gmail app. I only have one account set up in there. I have no control over the notification schedule for the app. This problem occurs on my iPhone and iPod Touch, both 6.1, which is why I use both terms interchangeably. Neither are jailbroken. I have noticed no pattern.

Comment: Is this problem still around?

Comment: No I don't think I've experienced this lately. Although at one point I had a problem where emails not marked as "important" (via Gmail's "importance" filter) appeared as notifications, when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

This sound weird per-se. I use the Gmail app for a long time now on my iPhone 5 and never have I received back-dated notification, especially if I removed it (via the x button) from the Notification screen.

I suppose this could occur if you leave your Gmail message unread in your inbox AND you restart your iPhone or the Gmail app.

Also, go to Settings > Notifications > Show > 1 Recent Item (instead of the default 5 recent Items).

Comment: You can't remove items from the lock screen individually if I recall. I think you are thinking of the Notification Center, while I am talking about the Lock Screen.